# PHP Class - public variable not displaying correctly outside class

Tags: php, class, public

In myClass I have declared `$_total_results_found = 0`

Then in my function I changed the value of `$_total_results_found = 10`

But, when I try to call this outside myClass the value still shows me 0.

Please can any one help me how to write this code?

```
class myClass
{
  private $_total_rows_count = 0;
  public function foundResults()
  {
    $count = 10;
    $this->_total_rows_count = $count;
  }
} // end myClass


$myclass = new myClass();
echo $myclass->_total_results_found; // Value is showing 0 instead of 10
```

Comment: `_total_results_found` != `_total_rows_count`

Comment: `_total_results_found` is never assigned...

Comment: This code makes no sense. `$myclass = new myClass();` creates a new class object. Next you'd have to call the function `$myclass->foundResults()`. And in the end - you cannot access variables you declared `private` outside its class. Use public instead.

Comment: Also turn off the hiding of E_NOTICE errors and you will see that actually this code is erroraneous, I recommend having all errors showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?
class myClass
{
  public $_total_rows_count = 0;
  public function foundResults()
  {
    $count = 10;
    $this->_total_rows_count = $count;
  }
} // end myClass


$myclass = new myClass();
$myclass->foundResults();
echo $myclass->_total_rows_count; //will print 10
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared `_total_results_found` anywhere. The only variable you are using is `_total_rows_count`, which is private, so it's not accessible outside the class.